# Divergence theorem: Simple solid region OR compact region and piecewise smooth boundary

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-fields, divergence-operator

While searching for the statements of divergence theorem, I came across two different conditions:

$(1)$ In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement)
and [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_Theorem#Theorem), it is said that the volume should be compact and boundary should be piecewise smooth.

$(2)$ In Stewart's calculus book and [this website](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DivergenceTheorem.aspx) and a number of websites, it is said that the volume must be simple solid and nothing is said about boundary.

**So why are there two statements? Which one is more general?**

**Also what exactly is "piecewise smooth boundary"?**

I guess it means that the surface $S$ can be broken up into finite number of surfaces $S_1,S_2,S_3,...$ or $S_n$ all of which (considered separately) have a unique tangent plane at every point on each of the surfaces $S_n$.

Comment: Maybe, by "simple solid region" the author means "piecewise smooth boundary"?